# subgraph that verify certain condition

Tags: algorithms, graphs, np-hard, approximation

Given an undirected graph  $G=(V,E,p,c)$ and a positive integer $k$,   $p: V \longrightarrow R^+$  which associates a positive weights $p(v_i)$ to every node $v_i \in V$, and $c: E \longrightarrow R^+$  which associates a positive cost $c(e_{i,j})$ to every edge $e_{ij} \in E$. How can I find a  subgraph $G'=(V_{G'},E_{G'})$,  $V_{G'}\subseteq V$,  under constraint $ \forall v_i,v_j \in V_{G'}$ , $e_{i,j} \in E_{G'}$  with  the minimum number of vertices such that:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{v \in V_{G'}} p(v)-\sum_{e \in E_{G'}}c(e) \geq k
\end{equation}

I think this problem  is NP-hard (because it is an optimization problem), as there is a reduction from k-clique, is it true?   if yes, there is an approximate algorithm to find a near optimal solution? I try to solve this problem using ILP integer linear programming on cplex :

$min \sum_{v_i \in V} v_i$

subject to :

$\sum_{v_i=1} p(v)-\sum_{i\ne j,v_i=v_j=1 }c(e_{i,j}) \geq k$

$v_i,v_j \in \{0,1\}$

, but this solution is not useful when it comes to a very large graph .

Context of the problem :

Given a collection of $n$ sets $S=\{S_1,...,S_n\}$ and a integer $k$ how to find the minimum number of sets $m$ whose size of their union is greater than $k$ $ |\bigcup_{i=1}^{m} S_i|≥k$ .
I model this problem in the form of a graph where the $S$ represents the set of vertices, $p(v_i)=|S_i|$ and $c(e_{i,j})=|S_i \cap S_j|$ . So i obtain the problem described above.

For example,

[image]

if $k=12$ the solution is G'with $V_{G'}=\{v_2,v_5,v_6\}$  and $E_{G'}=\{e_{5,6}\}$.

Comment: I still don't see any statement in the question that the all edges between selected vertices must be selected...

Comment: you can look at the context of the problem to understand why  all edges between selected vertices must be selected .

Comment: @   j_random_hacker thank you for this clarification, I update my question

Comment: Thanks for fixing your question.  Unfortunately this problem is NP-hard: You could solve Clique by changing every edge to a non-edge, and every non-edge to an edge with very high weight, setting $p(v_i)=1$ for all $i$ and then setting $k$ to the size of the clique you want.  The only induced subgraphs of the new graph with weight $\ge k$ contain no edges and at least $k$ vertices, i.e. they are independent sets of size $\ge k$, corresponding to cliques of size $\ge k$ in the original graph.

Comment: It seems you make the problem complicated. [This paper](http://crab.rutgers.edu/~rajivg/publications/journal/jalg04.pdf) seems to solve your primary problem. BTW, you primary problem is NP-hard because it is exactly the set cover problem if $k=\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^nS_i\right|$.

Comment: @ xskxzr Thank you very much, that's exactly who I'm looking for.